# PHP: ob_end_flush() end session

Tags: php, session

It seems that `ob_end_flush()` causes implicit session closing. Is this intended behavior? I suppose the answer is 'yes', but can I somehow prevent it?

Here's description of the problem I've encountered. I'm using framework that uses custom session handler, I don't think it matters in this case, but just for information. The actual problem occurs when at some point in framework code `ob_end_flush()` is called. By logging custom session handler calls I notice that session write and close called in this case. It's so implicit that I cannot even debug it with Zend Debugger, only log it with error_log. So, after `ob_end_flush()` interaction with session still continued (I know, that may be wrong, but still this is the case) and in that situation, when previous session is already closed, new session with new id is started. New session has new id because cookie is not set at the moment. So, as the result, I got two separate sessions with two different ids.

The best solution for me would probably be disabling that implicit `ob_end_flush()` behavior, but I will accept any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ob_end_flush()` doesn't end session. You can check it with small script without all your framework workaround

Comment: Hmm, really? Need to check it. Maybe I'm getting it wrong, but I'm just setting breakpoint at ob_end_flush(), hitting "step over" key and right after that new session file is created (custom session write() does that). However I can't get to that write() call, because debugger doesn't go there, that's why I thought it's so implicit.

Answer (score 0):

While a slightly indirect answer, it's common practice (and sometimes recommended practice) to start an output buffer with the purpose of buffering the entire request. Doing so allows you to continue to use session and/or set headers (including redirects) long after you start "outputting" content. This should take care of your implicit session close issue. Just add an `ob_start()` call to the top of your bootstrap.

Comment: As I see in framework code, it already does ob_start() at right place, and it buffers entire request. The problem (at least as I see it) in that thing that session_write_close() once called at ob_end_flush() and once again at the end of request handling (when no more code to execute).
zerkms above told that ob_end_flush() doesn't end session, if it's so then I'm a bit messed.

Comment: Well, although it's indeed a "common practice", it is not a recommended one by any means. The only good practice would be to have such an application design, which would never do any output without a reason.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, nothing wrong with disagreement, but I can definitely point out a few use cases where output buffering is absolutely recommended. I'm rather surprised to see you state that there's only one good practice here. Clearly the best practice is determined contextually.