# session not passes after redirecting page to another server and returning back in php

Tags: php, session, redirect, curl

I have a page that stores a data in an array session and redirects to another page on other server and then redirects to a page on the first sever but after redirecting the session variable is not no longer valid 
this is my first page that redirects to another page notice that the function send and get are using curl to send some arguments

```
<?php ob_start();
include_once("includes/student_session.php");
confirm_logged_in();
?>
<?php include("includes/connection.php");?>
<?php
$message="";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { $total_price=0;
    session_start();
      $_SESSION['ex_ids']=array();
      foreach($_POST['azmoon'] as $exam)   {
        $exam_id=$exam;
      $query1="select price from exam where exam_id={$exam_id}";
      $result1=mysqli_query($cnn,$query1);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
      $total_price+=$row['price'];
      array_push($_SESSION['ex_ids'],$exam_id);

    }
        $_SESSION['total_price']=$total_price;

     ?>
 <?php  ?>
<?php include_once("includes/sender.php");

$api='';
$redirect = '';
$url = '';
$result=send($url,$api,$total_price,$redirect);
if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result)){
    $go = "";
    if (headers_sent()) {
        die("Redirect failed. Please click on this link: <a href={$go}>");
    }
    else{
        exit(header("Location: ".$go));
    }
}
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

and this is the page that will load after redirecting from other server

```
$result = get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get);
$message = "";
if($result == 1){
    $student_id=$_SESSION[$student_id];
    foreach($_SESSION['ex_ids'] as $exam_id){
        echo $exam_id;

    }
$message = '';
   // header('Location: ');
}
```

i checked the error log on the server and it says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` first i thought it is because i did not put `ob_end_flush();` at the end of the first page i added that to the end of the page but it is still not working so what are the other reasons might be for such error

Comment: maybe this can help you???http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598260/php-ob-end-flush-end-session

Comment: Is there anything the user should do with the file on the other server? If not, why don't you just put the stuff in a db, exec it on the other server with the data from db and go to the next page without switching servers

Comment: @michael i can not access the other server cause that's a payment service

Comment: ok, I see, too bad...

Comment: @michael i did not actually understand what was the problem but since i tried almost every thing on my mind i changed the path for storing sessions and now it works correctly thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize sessions on every .php file where you want to access the $_SESSION variable. You don't seem to have done that in the second file.

Comment: i do initialize the sessions, not only this session but no other sessions is now has a valid amount...

Comment: Paste the full second page, or at least from the actual top.

Comment: i did not actually understand what was the problem but since i tried almost every thing on my mind i changed the path for storing sessions and now it works correctly thanks for the response